# Keen Non-Measurable Set - Well Known?

Tags: real-analysis

There's a "construction" of a non-measurable set that seems very keen to me; wondering whether anyone's seen it before.

Tedious part:

For $n,j\in\mathbb Z$ define the *dyadic interval* $I_{n,j}$ by $$I_{n,j}=[j2^{-n},(j+1)2^{-n}).$$

If $I$ is a half-open interval say $I_L$ and $I_R$ are the left half and right half of $I$, and say $|I|$ is the length of $I$. Note that $t\mapsto t+|I|/2$ maps $I_L$ onto $I_R$.

For $n=1,2,\dots$ the *Rademacher function* $r_n:[0,1)\to\{1,-1\}$ is defined by $$r_n=\sum_{j=0}^{2^{n}-1}(-1)^j\chi_{I_{n,j}}.$$(Draw a picture of $r_1$ and $r_2$ if this is your first time.)

Define $$f_n=\prod_{j=1}^nr_j.$$And note this: If $I=I_{n,j}$, $t\in I_L$ and $m>n$ then $$f_m(t+|I|/2)=-f_m(t).$$

Fun part:

Note that $$f_n\in K=\{1,-1\}^{[0,1)}.$$Here $K=\{1,-1\}^{[0,1)}$ is the set of all functions mapping $[0,1)$ to $\{1,-1\}$, which is *compact* in the product topology. Let $f$ be an accumulation point in $K$ of the sequence $(f_n)$.

It follows that if $I$ is a dyadic interval and $t\in I_L$ then $$f(t+|I|/2)=-f(t).$$And hence $f$ cannot be measurable:

If $f$ were measurable then we would have $\int_If=0$ for every dyadic interval $I$, so the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem would imply $f=0$ almost everywhere, which isn't so. (We've shown that $f$ measurable implies $0\in\{1,-1\}$; we leave it as an exercise to derive the canonical contradiction $0=1$ from this.)

Seems neat to me. Like $f$ can't be measurable because it has too much symmetry or something. "Constructing" a non-measurable function as the limit of a *net* of step functions...

So. We seen this before or can I call it the Ullrich function or what?

Comment: What do you mean by "keen"?

Comment: Cool. Interesting. Perfectly cromulent.

Comment: Nice one. Let me guess... You came up with this to hide the fact, that you are using choice in order to avoid the usual comments on the matter? ;-)

Comment: Heh. No, there's going to be a section explaining why those usual comments are silly (and why it's silly for authors to point out that they're using AC in one place when in fact they've been using it in other places without comment). However/whyever I came up with it, it sort of sticks in my head because it's like I can almost "see" what $f$ must look like, being a limit of the $f_n$.